# Recursive method to get all children doesn't work sometimes

Tags: typescript

I have a tree modelled by objects

```
export interface MyObject { title: string; children: MyObject[] }
```

where `children` does contain the *direct* children (which contain themselves their direct children again and so on).

Now I want to write a method to get all children of one object in depth.

My recursive attempt:

```
private getAllChildrenOf(myObject: MyObject, allObjects: MyObject[]): MyObject[] {
    const children = myObject.children;
    myObject.children.forEach(child => children.push(...this.getAllChildrenOf(child, allObjects)));
    return children;
}
```

This seems to work usually. But sometimes this method does not return *all* children but all children until some depth, i.e. some "grandchildren" are missed. I verified that the children (and the children of the children, etc.) in `myObject` are built correctly.

Unfortunately, I couldn't find out why the method doesn't work (and why only sometimes) and that's why I ask this question. Does anybody see an obvious mistake in the implementation of `getAllChildrenOf` which causes this?

Comment: Did you try let instead of const for children variable?

Comment: What is `allObjects` for in this method?  And it looks like you're *modifying* the array of children within the structure, rather than collecting the children into a new array.  If you're actively modifying the arrays you're looping over and recursing into, I'd expect some strange behavior.

Comment: This is mostly a guess worth testing, but... Instead of creating a direct reference to the object's `children` array, create a *new* array: `const children = [...myObject.children];`

Comment: you are in fact modifying the collection you iterating. this usually is not a good idea. either create a copy or a new array to return.

Comment: @David a historical leftover :-) we don't need it.

Comment: @MarkusDresch and David, thanks! Spontaneousely, I couldn't reproduce the bug again. I'll give it some more tries and if the bug doesn't occur again, then I think, this is the solution. Can somebody explain why this exactly produced such a behavior?

Comment: @ATW: As mentioned earlier, this recursive function is modifying the arrays over which it iterates.  You're looping over `myObject.children` while pushing entries onto `myObject.children`, and doing this recursively for all child objects/arrays.  This is going to modify the data in strange and unexpected ways.  The function should *probably* create and return a new array, rather than modify the existing array.